# Code after fragment is removed still executing

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, linked-list, queue

I have a quiz app and once all questions have been answered I want the fragment to be removed. The questions variable is a Queue of user-defined objects.

```
private void loadNextQuestion() {
        if (QuizGameActivity.questions.isEmpty()) {
            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(thisFragment).commit();
        }
        mCurrentQuestion = QuizGameActivity.questions.remove();
        ...
    }
```

But if I run this and answer the last question I receive a java.util.NoSuchElementException from the line that is trying to remove the next  question in the queue. Why is this line even executing if the queue is empty? The above if statement is supposed to prevent that?

Comment: you need an `else` case , don't you think?

Comment: *Why is this line even executing if the queue is empty?* Because it's not in the `else` block. It will always be executed. And yes, the method will continue the execution even if you remove the fragment: it's still a method, unless you return explicitly, it will continue its execution.

Comment: Looks like you probably need an "else" on your "if" to me.

Answer (score 0):

You are using procedural language i.e Java. Where execution of code is run step by step until the last statement reached.

**If you don't want the line to execute place it in else part or place a return statement**.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you'll need an `else` block. Your current code will **always** run `mCurrentQuestion = QuizGameActivity.questions.remove();`

Simply change it to the following: (Sorry if it's not exactly what you're trying to do! I wasn't able to fully comprehend your intentions)

```
private void loadNextQuestion() {
    if (QuizGameActivity.questions.isEmpty()) {
        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(thisFragment).commit();
    } else {
        mCurrentQuestion = QuizGameActivity.questions.remove();
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are writing code in procedural language i.e Java that executes code step by step.

If you want to get rid of error just add else part to you if condition and place the line there.

Other than this you can just add return; inside the if condition. So that no code after this executes.